# Area of Intersection between two polygon files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, attribute-joins, area

I'm new to mapping concepts and software.

I need to report on the intersecting area of postcode polygons and NBN Rollout areas. So postcode 3000 has 3 units of area in rollout region 1 and 6 units of area in rollout region 2.

Postcode polygons come in an ESRI Shapefile.
NBN Rollout regions come in a KML file.

I've loaded both into QGIS, saved them into a new file with CRS = EPSG 4326 then loaded these new files. Now the layers have the same CRS.

I then went to Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location.

Here are the settings I've selected:

[image: Settings for intersect.]

That runs for a few minutes before throwing this error:

[image: Error message]

The log messages panel gives the following log entry:

> Uncaught error while executing algorithm          Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>               File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py",
>   line 203, in execute
>                 self.processAlgorithm(progress)
>               File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\SpatialJoin.py",
>   line 158, in processAlgorithm outFeat.setGeometry(f.geometry())
>   TypeError: QgsFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry): argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'NoneType'

The final output I want to see is something like this:

```
postcode    rollout_region  area
3000        1               27
3000        2               44
3141        4               94
3141        6               46
3006        8               70
3006        9               41
3006        11              38
```

if the problem can be solved more easily in some other open source software I'm happy to try that.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS doesn't like you trying to join polygon to polygon this way. It doesn't know what to do with the geometry (`QgsFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'`). It would better work with a mix point/polygon.

You rather need some [Union tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_overlay_tools.html#union) if you want to keep all of the input geometry (below A area, plus A x B overlay area, plus B area). You will then have some data in the attribute table, that you can use afterwards in Excel.

- Make sure each rollout area has a unique id, each postcode area its unique
  postcode code.
- Do the Union, then update an area field.
- Then export to Excel.
- With a pivot table, you'll have your info.

[image: Union]

> ## Union
>
> ### Description
>
> *This algorithm combines the feature(s) of both layers. Features that lie partially within the other layer’s features will be split. Areas
> that lie within both layers will be added as new features. If any
> features are selected in either of the layers, then only those
> features are used in the operation. If no features are selected then
> the operation is performed using all features.*
>
> ### Parameters
>
> - Input layer [vector: any] : One layer containing feature(s) to be    unioned.
> - Input layer 2 : [vector: any] : Second layer containing    feature(s)    to be unioned.
>
> ### Outputs
>
> - Union [vector] : Where to save the union layer. Can be saved to file, a temporary file or a memory layer.

Nb : If you only need A x B area, you'd rather need to look out at the [Intersect](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_overlay_tools.html?highlight=intersect#intersection) tool

Answer (score 2):

Following @gisinside (I chose `Intersect` option), my suggestion is a **Virtual Layer**.

(1) An experimental data

- `postcode` polygon layer: `id` and `code` fields. (`code`= 3000, 3006, 3141)
- `nbn` polygon layer: `id` and `rollout` fields. (`rollout`= 1, 6, 8, 11)

[image]

(2) Go to `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer`

- Click on <kbd>Import</kbd> and embed these two (`postcode` and `nbn`) layers.

[image]

- Please modify below Query to fit your layer name and fieldname
- In this example I chose EPSG:3857 to reproject, but it is known for its inaccuracy in distance/area. **Please choose appropriate CRS**.

Query:

```
SELECT postcode.code, nbn.rollout, 
       st_area(st_transform(setsrid(st_intersection(                                       
               postcode.geometry, nbn.geometry
               ), 4326), 3857)) AS area_m2 
FROM postcode CROSS JOIN nbn 
ON st_intersects(postcode.geometry, nbn.geometry) = 1
```

(3) You will obtain a table something like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer ! I didn't even know about this feature, thanks.